# How to migrate 'on conflict do nothing' from PostgreSQL to Snowflake?

Tags: upsert, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am migrating a huge chunk of PostgreSQL script to work in Snowflake. The problem that stopped me is `on conflict` syntax and specifically when you use `on conflict do nothing`.

```
insert into table1
  select 
    user_id
  , something_else
from table2
on conflict do nothing;
```

Some propose the "equivalent" of `on conflict` from Postgres is using `merge into`, [some are not happy about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-to-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql). However when you use `merge into` you have to specify an `on <CONDITION>` clause, e.g. `merge into t1 using t2 on t1.id = t2.id ...`.

But in case of `on conflict do nothing` what should be the alternative?

When using `merge into` is there a less verbose syntax than specifying every column in these cases? (Imagine you have 15 columns and you have to write *every one of them*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (assumes you want to use user_id for uniqueness criteria)

```
merge into table1
using (select user_id, something_else from table2) sub
on sub.user_id = table1.user_id
when not matched then insert values(sub.user_id, sub.something_else)
```

Or simply eliminate the rows that have an existing `user_id`

```
insert into table1
select user_id, something_else from table2
where user_id not in (select user_id from table1)
```

Or if you want to prevent only full row duplicates, do

```
insert into table1 ( 
  select user_id, something_else from table2
  minus
  select * from table1
)
```

Comment: The last one is the closest I think, since I have checked and not all of the tables have unique ids. I will accept when I confirm it worked out! Thanks!